Reporting to Google Analytics, of push notification only works in debug mode but not in release mode
I would like to analyze when our users open push notifications, so I report the opening event to Google Analytics, intercepting it using UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate. This works very well during testing.
However after running the app for a couple of weeks with this code, I see on GA that this event only shows from my location/city and my device...
You might think none of our thousands of users ever opened any notification, but I do have colleagues in other cities and countries who opened the notifications many times helping to test the app. In addition we see a spike of active users when we send a push, so we know people are opening them. But I see none of them in GA.
This brings me to a possible conclusion that this code only works when the app is in debug mode, and not in a release version.
In general I don't have this problem with other GA events, they seem to be working well in production.
Any idea what is happening here?
This is the code I am using:
extension NotificationsManager: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
   
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse) async{
        
        if let value = response.notification.request.content.userInfo["notificationName"] as? String {
            Analytics.logEvent("notification_opened", parameters: [
                AnalyticsParameterItemName: value ])
        
        }
    }
} 

